# Sorting with negative and positive values in Datatable jQuery

Tags: sorting, datatables, datatables-1.10, columnsorting

I need to add the sorting functionality for the specific column which contains both positive and negative numbers.

By default, sorting is working as expected. But in my case, i need to sort the **positive values** only.

**Column: Percent**

**Values:** -1% 16% 2% 12% 0%

**Expected output:** 
Ascending order: 2% 12% 16% 0% -1%

Descending order: 16% 12% 2% 0% -1%

Any ideas how to do sorting like this?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create a custom sorting plugin that does that yourself. You could do as the example below :

```js
function ignoreZeroOrBelow(a, b, high) {
    a = parseFloat(a);
    a = a>0 ? a : high;
    b = parseFloat(b);
    b = b>0 ? b : high;
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));    
}
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "sort-positive-numbers-only-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ignoreZeroOrBelow(a, b, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    },
    "sort-positive-numbers-only-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ignoreZeroOrBelow(a, b, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)*-1;
    }
});
```

Usage :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { type: 'sort-positive-numbers-only', targets : 0 }
    ],
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/scuo0t6k/**

The idea behind the plugin is very simple

1. extract the number value of the content (`-1%` == `-1`)
2. when sorting

   - upon ascending return `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` if the value<=0
   - upon descending return `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` if the value<=0

By that only values>0 are included when you sort the column.